# Chars with diacritics not responding to css font-weight

Tags: html, css, fonts

I'm doing a site which includes pages that are translated into Vietnamese. In some places the characters with Vietnamese diacritics are appearing as bolder than the adjacent chars without.

After digging around, I found that adding a `font-weight` to the class for that text caused the change. I set a `font-weight` of `400` for this paragraph, which lightened the text for the chars without diacritics, but left the chars with diacritics as bolder.

I'd like to know why this is happening, and what I could do to keep the font-weight that I originally set. Charset for the page is UTF-8. Thanks much.

[image: Screenshot of the text]

Comment: Note that this also happened for the Cyrillic characters on the Russian version.

Comment: Which font are you using? Try another font.

Comment: What is your CSS for this? I assume there's a set of @font-face rules involved, what are they?

Comment: it's just Open Sans from Google:
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Open Sans Light'), local('OpenSans-Light'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v13/DXI1ORHCpsQm3Vp6mXoaTSYtBUPDK3WL7KRKS_3q7OE.woff2) format('woff2');
}
and then the other weights are loaded also